# C# Canonical file names

Tags: c#, filesystems, filenames

How to get canonical file name by non-canonical one.

E.g. I want to call function which converts `"C:\Program files\..\Windows\aaa.txt"` to `"C:\Windows\aaa.txt"`

I am looking for something like Java [File.getCanonicalPath()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalPath%28%29)

Comment: is [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx) what you looking for?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the [`Path.GetFullPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) method for this.

Example:

```
Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\Program files\..\Windows\aaa.txt"));
```

Output:

> C:\Windows\aaa.txt

Comment: It's good but be warned it's not a full replacement of CanonicalPath - Java's CanonicalPath will do things like normalize the capitalization of drive letters inside the path, and that is not happening in .NET's GetFullPath... In .NET the `Path` class has a GetFullPath method and there is similar functionality in the FullName property of `FileInfo`.

Answer (score 3):

```
System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("C:/Program files/../Windows/aaa.txt")
```

will return

```
"C:\\Windows\\aaa.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion:

```
string path = Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\Program files\..\Windows\aaa.txt");
```